# Vertically align elements to the bottom of their parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 columned footer and I need all elements inside to be aligned vertically to the bottom. At the moment, the divs have are aligned to the top: http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/SMtW6/1/

```
.col33 {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 90%;
}

.col33 > ul, .col33 > p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

However, because this is just a snippet of a much larger site, I'm hesitant to make those floats into `inline-blocks`. Is there any markup or CSS I can add, to make the children of `.col33` vertically align to the bottom?

Comment: Check my answer. Hope it will help you to solve your problem. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer so that it may help other users.

Answer (score 1):

Update the CSS of `col33` to

```
.col33 {
  width: 33%;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/SMtW6/3/

Answer (score 0):

Update .col33 as mentioned below :

> - Remove **float:left**
> - Add **display:table-cell**
> - Add **vertical-align:middle**

Check below css for the same :

```
.col33 {
    width: 33%;
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 90%;;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMtW6/10/)**